# How do I run a forEach for two different arrays?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I have generated two arrays and then used a function which populates some variables depending on which element in the array was clicked. (See first code snippet) But, now I want to run a function which uses the populated variables. (See second code snippet)

```
var wordEl;
var ansEl;
var wordId;
var ansId;

englishWords.forEach(function (el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", populateWord, false);
      function populateWord() {
        wordEl = el;
        wordId = el.getAttribute("id");
      }
    });

germanWords.forEach(function (el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", populateAns, false);
      function populateAns() {
        ansEl = el;
        ansId = el.getAttribute("data-id");
      }
    });
```

The code below shows the function I want to run, but I don't know where/how to insert it. I keep getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')", however, when I run this in the console, it works.

```
    function checkAnswer() {
      if (wordId == ansId) {
        wordEl.remove();
        ansEl.remove();
      } else {
        alert("Incorrect! Please try again.");
      }
    }
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<table>
  <td><div class="englishbutton" id="word1">introspection</div></td>
  <td><div class="englishbutton" id="word2">antidote</div></td>
  <td><div class="englishbutton" id="word3">ambiguous</div></td>
  <td><div class="englishbutton" id="word4">braggart</div></td>
  <td><div class="englishbutton" id="word5">alleviate</div></td>
</table>

<table>
    <td><div class="germanbutton" id="ans1" data-id="word1">Selbstbeobachtung</div></td>
    <td><div class="germanbutton" id="ans2" data-id="word1">Gegenmittel</div></td>
    <td><div class="germanbutton" id="ans3" data-id="word1">zweideutig</div></td>
    <td><div class="germanbutton" id="ans4" data-id="word1">Angeber</div></td>
    <td><div class="germanbutton" id="ans5" data-id="word1">lindern</div></td>
 </table>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML too as an [mcve]? I think I know what you're trying to do (check if the English word clicked on is the same as the German word that's clicked on, and if it is remove both words from the lists) but it would be good to clarify that point.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry about that! I will update this question now.

Comment: I've copied your snippets and added the necessary glue code. It works: https://jsfiddle.net/jse94poa/ First, click a word in one language. Then, click a word in the other language. Then, click `Check`. I would add some checks: `if (wordId == ansId)` => `if (wordEl && ansEl && wordId == ansId)` or another case with a different error message, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/jse94poa/1/

Comment: Hi jabaa, that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a button to call the function:

```js
var wordEl;
var ansEl;
var wordId;
var ansId;

const englishWords = document.querySelectorAll('.englishbutton');
const germanWords = document.querySelectorAll('.germanbutton');

englishWords.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", populateWord, false);

  function populateWord() {
    wordEl = el;
    wordId = el.getAttribute("id");
  }
});

germanWords.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", populateAns, false);

  function populateAns() {
    ansEl = el;
    ansId = el.getAttribute("data-id");
  }
});

function checkAnswer() {
  if (!wordEl) {
    alert("Click an English word");
    return;
  }
  if (!ansEl) {
    alert("Click a German word");
    return;
  }
  if (wordId == ansId) {
    wordEl.remove();
    ansEl.remove();
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect! Please try again.");
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    <div class="englishbutton" id="word1">introspection</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="englishbutton" id="word2">antidote</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="englishbutton" id="word3">ambiguous</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="englishbutton" id="word4">braggart</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="englishbutton" id="word5">alleviate</div>
  </td>
</table>

<table>
  <td>
    <div class="germanbutton" id="ans1" data-id="word1">Selbstbeobachtung</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="germanbutton" id="ans2" data-id="word2">Gegenmittel</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="germanbutton" id="ans3" data-id="word3">zweideutig</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="germanbutton" id="ans4" data-id="word4">Angeber</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="germanbutton" id="ans5" data-id="word5">lindern</div>
  </td>
</table>

<button onclick="checkAnswer()">
  Check
</button>
```